# Biq query: Resources exceeded during query execution

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi we have a SP in Bigquery with parameters and can expect length more than 100k

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `Procname`(Criteria ARRAY<STRING>, Criteria2 STRING)
BEGIN
   
     DECLARE Total INT64 DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE Invalid STRING ;
     DECLARE InvalidCount INT64 ;
      
     
--#1 Get Total
   SET Total = (SELECT SUM(numbers) FROM `table` WHERE Number IN UNNEST  (Criteria));

--#2 Get List of numbers not found and return with comma seperated
    execute immediate concat("SELECT STRING_AGG(Invalid) AS Invalid, count(Invalid)
    as InvalidCount FROM (SELECT Invalid FROM(SELECT '' as Invalid union all  select ",Criteria2," )v  
    EXCEPT DISTINCT SELECT Postcode FROM `table`)") INTO Invalid,InvalidCount;
    
         SELECT  Total, Invalid, InvalidCount;
END;
```

where my Criteria is an array of string and Criteria2 is a string`'number1' union all select 'number2' union all select 'invalidnumber' union all select 'number3' union all select 'anotherinvalidnumber'`

so as per above SP say with Criteria as `['number1', 'number2','invalidnumber','number3' ,'anotherinvalidnumber']` and Criteria2 as above the result should be
[image]

The problem is on Criteria2 parameter as soon as I increase this string length I got this error as

> Message[Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough
> resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too
> complex..

which is believe is due to a lot of select '' union all.

two questions

1. Any better way to write query #2 taking performance into account, we tried with temp tables but performance is an issue. If we go with this approach then Bigquery API is not liking it
2. How to get rid of this error

Comment: Can you give some idea of what your input and output should look like.  Struggling to understand what to code is supposed to do.

Comment: Input is comma separated values, output should be  #1 Total of the found input from the table and #2 return back those  values if not found in table comma separated

Comment: @v0rl0n - Added more clarity on the question